# A Pythonic way to reshape Pandas.DataFrame's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]
I have a Pandas.DataFrame on the left.
I'd like to reshape it into the form on the right.
Numbers of values of each label (a, b and c) are the same.

What I'm doing now is creating a new DataFrame and then appending values of each label onto it by adding each column.
It definitely works but, as far as I know, Pandas.DataFrame is very powerful and I believe there must be more Pythonic way to do the task.

Any helps will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df["count"] = df.groupby("label").cumcount()

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  label  value  count
0     a    0.2      0
1     a    0.1      1
2     a    0.4      2
3     b    0.5      0
4     b    0.2      1
5     b    0.6      2
6     c    0.7      0
7     c    0.9      1
8     c    0.3      2

In [13]: df.pivot_table("value", "count", "label")
Out[13]:
label    a    b    c
count
0      0.2  0.5  0.7
1      0.1  0.2  0.9
2      0.4  0.6  0.3
```

---

If you can garauntee the order and number in each group, you could just reshape:

```
In [21]: df["value"].values.reshape((-1, 3)).T
Out[21]:
array([[ 0.2,  0.5,  0.7],
       [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.9],
       [ 0.4,  0.6,  0.3]])
```

you can make this a DataFrame with:

```
In [22]: pd.DataFrame(df["value"].values.reshape((-1, 3)).T, 
                      columns=df.loc[::3, "label"])
Out[22]:
label    a    b    c
0      0.2  0.5  0.7
1      0.1  0.2  0.9
2      0.4  0.6  0.3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is most concise and readable one! I can guarantee the order. After I reshape and transpose the values of DataFrame, what is the best way to assign the values to a new DataFrame? Could you add it into your answer? Thanks again!

Comment: @Pandaaaaaaa edited, I think I prefer the pivot_table though :)

Comment: What's cool is that you don't even need to create other column... just pass it to `pivot_table`... `df.pivot_table('value', df.groupby('label').cumcount(), 'label')`

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've never used pivot table before, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it ~ :-) no need create other column

```
    df=df.sort_values('label')# in case you do have disordered df
    pd.crosstab(df.index%3,df.label,df.value,aggfunc='sum')
    Out[600]: 
    label    a    b    c
    row_0               
    0      0.2  0.5  0.7
    1      0.1  0.2  0.9
    2      0.4  0.6  0.3
```

Comment: @PaulH Right , I assuming he have a ordered df, adding it right now ~ :-)

Comment: I can guarantee the order! I don't think sorting is necessary for now. Thank you very much for bringing Pandas.crosstab to my attention!

Comment: @Pandaaaaaaa Yw ~ :-) , the key is `df.index%3`

Answer (score 2):

This is my entertainment.  If you like the answers... good!

**Option 1**

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in df.values.tolist():
    d[k].append(v)

pd.DataFrame(d)

     a    b    c
0  0.2  0.5  0.7
1  0.1  0.2  0.9
2  0.4  0.6  0.3
```

---

**Option 2**

```
pd.concat({
    n: g.reset_index(drop=True)
    for n, g in df.groupby('label').value
}, axis=1)

     a    b    c
0  0.2  0.5  0.7
1  0.1  0.2  0.9
2  0.4  0.6  0.3
```

---

**Option 3**

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.label.values)
c = np.eye(u.size, dtype=int)[f].cumsum(0)[np.arange(f.size), f] - 1
a = np.empty((c.max() + 1, u.size))
a[c, f] = df.value.values
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=u)

     a    b    c
0  0.2  0.5  0.7
1  0.1  0.2  0.9
2  0.4  0.6  0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `.pivot`:

```
res = (df.pivot(columns='label', values='value')
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)))
print(res)
# label    a    b    c
# 0      0.2  0.5  0.7
# 1      0.1  0.2  0.9
# 2      0.4  0.6  0.3
```